# Azure Functions app not giving any kind of output & eventually giving error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I try to run my nodejs based Azure Function, I'm experiencing an issue where it doesn't generate any feedback and in some cases, I end up getting the following message:

```
2017-04-05T00:18:15.969 Exception while executing function: Functions.AddAuthor. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Thread was being aborted.
```

All my function code is publicly available, you can see it [here](https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure/blob/master/functions/AddAuthor/index.js#L24).  The library it's using works locally.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to why it doesn't want to work in Azure Functions.

I originally posted this over at the [Azure Functions github repo](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/240), but it was suggested that I maybe ask here.

Additionally, it seems like even a simple `context.log` [won't even work](https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/84164302163f44409234e3d411bb2341).

Comment: Your Function code calls anecdoteService.close().  Where is anecdoteService declared?

Comment: It's all part of this library, and `close` is found here: https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-engine/blob/master/src/Engine/Service.ts#L50 - Although this library deliberately doesn't have anything functions specific inside of it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the library, so anecdote.service is different from anecdocteService?

Comment: What I meant to ask is - are the methods close() and addAuthor(...) from the same class? If yes, shouldn't the object name be the same?  You have anecdote.service.addAuthor(..) but anecdoteService.close().

Comment: I've updated it, but I'm still getting the same result.  Moreover, I'm also not able to trigger any output even if I replace all my code with something like `context.log`.  It just feels like the whole thing is dead.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice - `context` does not exist in this scope: https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure/blob/master/functions/index.js#L13

If I set up a similar function I see:

> 2017-04-12T17:06:55.433 Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.ManualJS. mscorlib: ReferenceError: context is not defined
>       at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ManualJS\test.js:1:63)

Also, 'anecdoteService' is not defined in this scope.

```
anecdote.service
    .addAuthor(author)
    .then(function () { anecdoteService.close()})
    .then(function () { context.log("End of line")})
```

Does the function work with the [azure-functions-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-cli)?

Looking at the gist you provided, did you provide a function?

```
// index.js
module.exports = function(context) {
  context.log('hello');
  //there needs to be a context.done or your function will not finish
}
```

or was it simply

```
// index.js
context.log('hello'); // there's no context object, no function, etc
```

Comment: I know it sounds strange, but I'm not using the Azure Functions CLI.  In part because I haven't set it up, but also in part because I really wish they'd release a platform independent version.  I don't mind proprietary, but platform independence is a must.  I think the larger issue here is that I'm not getting any actionable feedback from the Functions portal though.

Comment: As I mentioned above, one issue is that even if I remove all my code and replace it with `context.log("hello?!")`, I still end up with no output.  It's like the whole thing is dead.

Comment: Wasn't sure what to make of the gist, edited my answer above for the code formatting.

Comment: You can see the full code here: https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-azure/blob/master/functions/AddAuthor/index.js#L24